# How I can see the native intern Magento 2 UI library?

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, documentation

I run the **grunt documentation** but I can't be able to see the docs, I saw a 404 page, why?

```
http://dev.local/redstore/lib/web/css/docs/index.html
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you'll need to remove the file or authorize your IP on `lib/.htaccess` file.

Is necessary access with **index.html** on the URL too, like you did.

Like this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 172.22.0.1
```

But you don't need to this to see the documentation, is public on this link below and is the same content.

https://magebr.github.io/Magento-2-UI-library/index.html

[image]